# prepend,append-Sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer

### Task

The prepend,append-Sequence is defined recursively, like this

- a(1) = 1
- a(n) = a(n-1).n  , if n is even
- a(n) = n.a(n-1)  , if n is odd

where the . represents an integer concatenation.

So the first few terms are: `1,12,312,3124,53124,531246,7531246,...` This is [A053064](http://oeis.org/A053064).

Your task is, given an integer **a > 0** to return **n**, such that the **n**th element in the prepend,append-Sequence is equal to **a** and if no such **n** exists return 0, a negative number or error out etc.

### Rules

- Input can be taken as an integer, string, list of characters/digits etc.
- Output can be printed to STDOUT or returned (integer, string etc. is fine)
- On invalid input & in the case no such **n** exists your program may do anything but return a positive integer (eg. loop forever, return 0 etc.)
- You may choose to use 0-indexing, but then the output in case no **n** exists cannot be 0

### Test cases

```
1 -> 1
12 -> 2
21 -> 0
123 -> 0
312 -> 3
213 -> 0
211917151311975312468101214161820 -> 21
2119171513119753102468101214161820 -> 0
333129272523211917151311975312468101214161820222426283031 -> 0
999795939189878583817977757371696765636159575553514947454341393735333129272523211917151311975312468101214161820222426283032343638404244464850525456586062646668707274767880828486889092949698100 -> 100
```

Comment: More formal: `a(n-1)*(int(log(n))+1)+n` and `n*(int(log(n))+1)+a(n-1)`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I would call that *less* formal :P

Comment: @JonathanAllan That is already in the question for ~10 minutes.

Comment: I suggest allowing errors for invalid inputs.

Comment: I suggest allowing undefined behaviour for invalid inputs.

Comment: Can we take input as a list of digits?

Comment: @Okx Yes, that's mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 6):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>83, 80, 60</strike> 59 bytes

```cs
n=>{int i=0;for(var t="";t!=n;)t=++i%2<1?t+i:i+t;return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDLattQFNz7K24NARunyT3vc6IoXRS6alZddG1U1VxIJCpdB4Lxt7uCbmva3cA8mJlu/tiNU385zmU4pG/vc@1fm1X3sp/n9Ou0muu@li69jeVHet6XYbM9rb4ch@5xrtNiuE1lqE/p0F6G9um04FTa3Pwcp83bfkq1Xa@b@qEdmm1td7tyg4/wqe7KQ9nVZurrcRpSac6XZvV5HObxpb/7PpXafy1Dvzls1gS43m6vkAgQYCBACzBZtKwOGRAYFBzzdStcpyLCQoICPNxcnBwszEyMDDTUVJQUJMREhAQ42FiYGCjISIiWKoGGgvTPjojIqOiUCYlJyTkzMrOySxYUFhXXrKisqm7Z0NjU3LOjs6t75MDg0FiS/4y@v/@/x/JfLzufL78B)

Takes the input as a string into a lambda function. 1-indexed. Returns the index of the value for truthy, or infitnitely loops for a "falsey"

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@EriktheOutgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer).*

```python
f=lambda x,i='1',j=2:i!=`x`and f(x,[i+`j`,`j`+i][j%2],j+1)or~-j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoAgEADQX7EhTLwGbQv8khA0JLqjTMLAln7dHN720pv3K@paN3P4cw2eFUDDFQcyesbOuOJ8DGwbCiwoHTloJNqFem2BpBLX/Y1U040xt4YxPXkQok5K/w)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

***-18 bytes thanks to [@officialaimm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59523/officialaimm), because I didn't notice erroring out was allowed!***

```python
x,i,j=input(),'1',1
while i!=x:j+=1;i=[i+`j`,`j`+i][j%2]
print j
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v0InUyfLNjOvoLREQ1NH3VBdx5CrPCMzJ1UhU9G2wipL29bQOtM2OlM7IStBB4i1M2Ojs1SNYrkKijLzShSy/v9XNzI2UQcA)**

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 82 bytes (does not loop forever)

This one returns `0` for invalid inputs.

```python
def f(n,t="",i=1):
 while len(t)<len(n):t=[t+`i`,`i`+t][i%2];i+=1
 print(n==t)*~-i
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU3LSgNBELzvVyyCsGsiTL@7o/sX3kIwghsyEMYQJgQv/vq60WMOgod60FRVHz/r/qPgNL2Pu3bXlWUd7u6WeYB@1bSXfT6M7WEsXe2fr1L6VR3WdbHN2@WMRd2s8z1unvJigKY9nnKpXRmG2j98Pebpt/5yOo@rXXd6u7zmcjzXru8naAAbvDI19GNpBgQYCNBsTOYzq0MCBAYFx3SbSDcRorkXaChIfw4iIqOiUyJoIsJCggI83FycHCzMTIwMNNRUlBQkxESEBDjYWJgYKMhI/vsbiUnJOTEys7JLEhQWFdekqKyqbsnQ2NTck6Ozq3ukwODQmJfTNw)**

Comment: Ninja'd :D [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcZNCoMwEAbQvaewi5KWzMJv/G0lJxHBjeAMJQaJqKdPXTx44YrL6jmlk4TUiQ97fL3JwBCyY5HfnMvDnV@1Dr24QeykE92sjIM@eczCJj7mmpJh4IMWNco7bV2Cq6ZDAUaFBh0X5g8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @officialaimm Thanks a lot! I didn't notice erroring out / loop forever was allowed.

Comment: Save a byte with a lambda: ``f=lambda x,i='1',j=2:i!=`x`and f(x,[i+`j`,`j`+i][j%2],j+1)or~-j``

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Wait, it throws recursion error for everything, although I set `sys.setrecursionlimit()`. Can you provide a tio?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Does it throw an error for `x=1`? Or `x=12`? I thought it only threw such an error for at least `x=151311975312468101214` or something.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It doesn't work for anything (for me) for some reason. Maybe you could provide a working link if it works for you?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder [It works for `x=1311975312468101214`.](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoMwEADAr@ihaMgWuqtVW8hLREiKSHdpY5AI6aVfjx7mNuEX36unnBfzcd/X7IoEbCqsQAw9uTQ2WefnYqkTjKytWDhpnka50ASiUa3b/yo5bOzj2diHPdZKZWwQH/29QWq7AW9I2B4)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer thanks, my bad

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

Takes input as a string. Throws a recursion error if no index is found.

```js
f=(n,s=k='1')=>n==s?k:f(n,++k&1?k+s:s+k)
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n,s=k='1')=>n==s?k:f(n,++k&1?k+s:s+k)

console.log(f('1')) // 1
console.log(f('12')) // 2
console.log(f('312')) // 3
console.log(f('211917151311975312468101214161820')) // 21
console.log(f('999795939189878583817977757371696765636159575553514947454341393735333129272523211917151311975312468101214161820222426283032343638404244464850525456586062646668707274767880828486889092949698100')) // 100
```

Comment: I *think* you can save a byte with this:  `f=(n,s=k='1')=>n-s?f(n,++k&1?k+s:s+k):k`

Comment: @RickHitchcock Unfortunately, that would force Number comparisons and introduce false positives on large inputs caused by the loss of precision.

Comment: Gotcha.  It works on the test cases but was unsure how it would handle other situations.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
Rs2ZU1¦ẎVµ€i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z@o2Cgq1PDQsoe7@sIObX3UtCbz////hkYA)

Explanation:

```
Rs2ZU1¦ẎVµ€i
         µ€  Eval this link for each (automatic [1..n] range)
R             Range
 s2           Split in pieces of: 2
   Z          Zip
    U1¦       Only keep index: 1 of: Vectorized reverse
       Ẏ      Flatten 1-deep
        V     Concatenate string versions and eval
           i Find index of y in x (y = implicit input)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
$vDNÌNFs}«})Ik
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fpczF73CPn1tx7aHVtZqe2f//GxkaWhqaG5oaGgMZ5qbGhkYmZhaGBoZGhiaGZoYWRgYA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##nU09akJhEOzfKYJdwGJ3Z2d/rCWlXcA2gpVlQAjEG@QmHkLwHezlS1qLQIoZhmF@hG8HPS6fZ/3Yvi7n7W7@2r28X@7Xy/P@tOxX823zNN9W60Untcl@GBN@JQa0NZWKIZLD9igVNXUNLZPHhDxEgNFrS6Phz0EzcwsrCHTq7mw2Wqsri4XS7MxkIjU6MhgIZTNJgurt6XS4opHgf78NjkC5uLl7eFFodAYrJCw8IiolLT0jq6SsvKKqpa29o8eyfAM)

**Explanation**

*0-indexed*.
Returns **-1** if the input is not in the sequence.

```
$                 # push 1 and input
 v                # for each y,N (element, index) in input do:
  D               # duplicate top of stack
   NÌ             # push N+2
     NF }         # N times do:
       s          # swap the top 2 elements on the stack
         «        # concatenate the top 2 elements on the stack
          })      # end loop and wrap in a list
            Ik    # get the index of the input in this list
```

Comment: Haha, this is basically my solution with the `g` removed and the append/prepend thing shortened. I'll delete my answer

Comment: @Okx: Oh yeah, I see you golfed yours down to almost exactly this only minutes after my post. Great minds ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 73 bytes

```r
p=paste0;n=scan(,'');l='';while(l!=n){F=F+1;l="if"(F%%2,p(F,l),p(l,F))};F
```

Reads from stdin and returns the value of the index (implicitly printed). Infinite loops when the value isn't in the sequence. `F` is by default `FALSE` which is cast to `0` when used in arithmetic.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8C2ILG4JNXAOs@2ODkxT0NHXV3TOsdWXd26PCMzJ1UjR9E2T7PazdZN2xAorJSZpqThpqpqpFOg4aaTowmkcnTcNDVrrd3@Gxsa/QcA)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>75</s> <s>71</s> 57 bytes

```
f n=[i|i<-[1..],(show=<<reverse[1,3..i]++[2,4..i])==n]!!0
```

Takes `n` as a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZLDsIgFAXQrbw2DjSlhAv0YwIrIQw6oCmxogFTJ@4d9YzOtpRb2PdaV0rWxU80vQPnnp3L9nhbY3I4Qi7BgSnOo@86J5n@72Jt8k0j6n2JiSw9c0wvOtFKrQSumDBA/TINClKPMwQkNEbMUrT1Cw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>17</s></sup> 15 bytes

```
£moiṁsṁṠehGJC2N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9Di3PzMhzsbi4H44c4FqRnuXs5Gfv///zcyNLQ0NDc0NTQGMsxNjQ2NTMwsDA0MjQxNDM0MLYwMAA)

1-indexed. Returns 0 if not in the sequence.

-2 bytes from Leo, `GJ`!

Comment: Nice, particularly the ```z*İ_``` trick to reverse alternate elements.  [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9Di3Ic7G4urtI5siHfP137UNiXX2u////9K5qbGhkYmZkoA) by using string input...

Comment: String input doesn't really work because values are not lexicographically ordered: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9Di3Ic7G4urtI5siHfP137UNiXX2u////9KRoaGlobmhqaGxkCGuamxoZGJmYWhgaGRoYmhmaGFkYESAA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: There is a shorter way by scanning with `J`, though: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9Di3PzMhzsbi4H44c4FqRnuXs5Gfv///zcyNLQ0NDc0NTQGMsxNjQ2NTMwsDA0MjQxNDM0MLYwMAA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 12 bytes

```
ɾɖ≬wJṘyRYvṅḟ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#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)
Uses 0-indexing, outputs -1 for invalid.

```
           ḟ # Find index of input in...
 ɖ           # Scan
ɾ            # range(1, input)
  ≬---       # by
   wJ        # Concatenate
     Ṙ       # Reverse
      yRY    # Reverse every other element
         vṅ  # Concatenate each list into a number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>115</s> 85 bytes

```hs
s=read.(show=<<)
f 1=1
f x|odd x=s[x,f$x-1]
f x=s[f$x-1,x]
g x=[n|n<-[1..],x==f n]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchBCoMwEEDRvacYwUWFJDh2mzlJyCIQo6IdxRQ6C@@ept18eH8JeZv2vZRM1xSieeTl@JC1fZMACWvlPmIEoexEpU40@t@s/EOJb@ZKxzdb7dAYr4QoAfu2HcorrEzntfK7m@GJI2iNOJQv)

Comment: @BruceForte I actually managed to save 30 thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 135 bytes

```
s=t={};x=1;While[x<5!,{s~AppendTo~#&,s~PrependTo~#&}[[x~Mod~2+1]]@x;AppendTo[t,FromDigits@Flatten[IntegerDigits/@s]];x++];t~Position~#&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>19 18</s>  15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
+ḂḶṚm2;RḤ$ṁµ€Vi
```

A monadic link taking and returning integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//K@G4guG4tuG5mm0yO1LhuKQk4bmBwrXigqxWaf///zMxMg)** (very slow - takes ~50s on TIO just to confirm that `3124` is at index `4`)

For a much faster version use the [previous 18 byter](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/74Y6mhzu2Pdw5K9fIOujhjiUqD3c2crn4HG5/1LQmLPP///9GhoaWhuaGpobGQIa5qbGhkYmZhaGBoZGhiaGZoYWRAQA) (only checks up to the length of the input, which is sufficient).

#### How?

```
+ḂḶṚm2;RḤ$ṁµ€Vi - Link: number, v
           µ€   - perform the monadic link to the left for €ach k in [1,2,3,...v]
                -                 (v can be big, lots of k values makes it slow!)
 Ḃ              -   modulo k by 2  = 1 if odd 0 if even
+               -   add to k = k+isOdd(k)
  Ḷ             -   lowered range = [0,1,2,...,k+isOdd(k)]
   Ṛ            -   reverse = [k+isOdd(k),...,2,1,0])
    m2          -   modulo slice by 2 = [k+isOdd(k),k+isOdd(k)-2,...,3,1]
         $      - last two links as a monad:
       R        -   range(k) = [1,2,3,...,k]
        Ḥ       -   double = [2,4,6,...,2k]
     ;          - concatenate = [k+isOdd(k),k+isOdd(k)-2,...,3,1,2,4,6,...,2k]
         ṁ      - mould like range(k) = [k+isOdd(k),k+isOdd(k)-2,...,3,1,2,4,6,...,k-isOdd(k)]
                -   (this is a list of the integers to be concatenated for index k)
             V  - evaluate as Jelly code (yields a list of the concatenated integers)
              i - first index of v in that (or 0 if not found)
```

Comment: How long would it take to compute `211917151311975312468101214161820`?

Comment: A long, long time :p

Comment: Yes, but how long?

Comment: Well looks like it's order **v**  squared where **v** is the input integer.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Technically you call that **⁸** :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 92 bytes

This loops infinitely for invalid cases, so I didn't include them in the testing link.

```swift
func f(x:String){var i="1",j=1;while i != x{j+=1;i=[i+String(j),String(j)+i][j%2]};print(j)}
```

**[Test Suite.](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5988a150357207286768e0b3)**

Amusingly, it is longer with a closure:

```swift
var f:(String)->Int={var i="1",j=1;while i != $0{j+=1;i=[i+String(j),String(j)+i][j%2]};return j}
```

**[Test Suite.](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5988a323357207286768e0b6)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 54 + 1 (-n) = 55 bytes

```perl
$a=++$,%2?$,.$a:$a.$,while length$a<length;say/$a/&&$,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxJasNQEEXRrWTw44llubpXTRqygixCAxEbhGxsQ8jm8yPI7MCFe51vC3pv0/t@34Zn@WjD2KaXNo1t@D6dl/lpmdevx6lNb/94vU8/xzYdd7s29F5VUSgtzspIpCZHRQRCg708HK7OKAQABVtZGEyNtTQUqspSEgJRYS4OBuuGwBbMk4mFjZ1TSERMXFJJRU1d08jEzNwSBIHBkU4ubu6eQSFh4ZFJKWnpmUUlZeW1nen3cn2cL@u9Hz4xElM/rH8)

Returns nothing if not found.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 17 bytes

```
@P=PiXv n X;¥P}a1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3yHANiAzokwhTyHC@tDSgNpEw///lYwMDS0NzQ1NDY2BDHNTY0MjEzMLQwNDI0MTQzNDCyMDJQA) or [check (valid) test cases](https://tio.run/##hY1BSkRBEEOv8um1QldVkqpiGPAIfyMMiItZKiguxJ3H8SJzsW/jBdw8Qggvr9ePz@PxtJ/HOB728/5y@dret8vp9rN/X@04noaNu2G@EH90s7Y0WqyQXCVUNs0NJiufa9Pd2exoq64sVpRlZyYz0tRKUSFjM0kGDY0EEbDoyGDEEren0@PfR3eHyytmeCAUhQkHIBQnnaBYmnJBUuVMT6SyapYXSlU92xutXuY5nrf7t18)

Takes input as a string or integer. On invalid input, continues "forever" looking for a solution (thus why I didn't include them in the test cases).

Explanation:

```
@P=PiXv n X;¥P}a1    
                     # Implicitly start with P = ""
@             }a1    # Repeat the function for each integer X > 0 until one returns true
 P=Pi     X          #  Insert X into P at index:
     Xv              #   X is divisible by 2?
        n            #   Times -1
           ;¥P       #  Return whether P now equals the input
                     # Implicitly output the last value of X
```

The "insert at index" portion might be a bit confusing, so I'll add more detail here. In Japt, `NvD` is a function which returns 1 if N is divisible by D, and 0 otherwise. If D is not provided, it defaults to 2. Thus `Xv`  here is equal to 1 if X is even, and 0 if X is odd. `NnD` is a function that returns `D - N`. If D is not provided it defaults to 0, effectively returning `-N`. In this program, that results in -1 if X is even, and still 0 if X is odd. Finally, in Japt indexing negative numbers count from the end of a string or array. Thus the segment `PiXv n X` evaluates to `Pi0 X` if X is odd, prepending X, but it evaluates to `Pi-1 X` if X is even, appending it instead.